# Need pointer on designing low pass filter circuit

Tags: filter, passive-filter

I am trying to design a low pass circuit for my project which can cutoff frequency of around 300 kHz. Input and output impedance is 50 ohm.

The values of R4, C3 which are part of the filter can be modified. But how do I size the component and still meet the cutoff frequency?

The circuit will be powered with an AC signal source.Purpose to is filter out all unwanted signal beyond 300kHz

Project requirement:

```
attenuation or gain in passband = 1.3 dB
ripple in passband for >=2nd order filters (>=0dB) = 0 ripple
stop band f-3dB = BW =300kHz
stop band f-60dB = RC filter
Source impedance= 50 ohm
Load impedance= 50 ohm
Limited to RC filter due to space constraint.
```

[image]

Comment: R3 and R2 are the fixed input and output impedance(Please let me know if i did the input and output impedance wrongly and gave you the wrong idea). R1 ,C1 and L1 is the RCL filter i am trying to design and the value can be changed. May i know if you can clarify on what do you mean by finding a formula for the formula for the voltage at R3?(the comment i was replying to was deleted)

Comment: That's a high pass filter not a low pass filter. Fix your post with the correct details. Also add what your actual signal is (bandwidth) and how much attenuation you are expecting to create at 300 kHz.

Comment: Hey you are right. That is why i cannot find any RCL low pass example. I am going to need some time to rethink my design. Thank you !

Comment: You also need to rethink over what bandwidth your input and output impedance of 50 ohm is going to be linear and fairly close to 50 ohm. A simple RLC filter isn't going to have a wide bandwidth where the input and output impedance remains close to 50 ohm. You need to consider this.

Comment: Ah i might be overthinking and using the wrong kind of filter for the purpose i wanted. Would a RC filter be more suitable for my low pass application? I need -3db at the cut off frequency of 300khz.

Comment: Any filter you choose will not present a constant 50 ohm input impedance and neither will it present a constant 50 ohm output impedance. YOU need to define what you want to happen and how rapidly the attenuation falls away as frequency rises higher than 300 kHz. There is no magic bullet to this - you have to specify what you want to happen.

Comment: i hope i am understanding this correctly but do you mean i need to select a Quality factor to determine the damping of filter after the cutoff frequency? I was given the 50ohm impedance and 50 ohm output impedance as the requirement for this project. Will this impedance scenario cause issues that i did not notice?Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: No, you need to define what you want your filter to do or achieve - i.e. what are your filtering requirements. Once you have defined them then you design the filter so, forget about Q for now. Forget about any form of circuit whatsoever and, define what you want it to achieve. You are miles away from defining your requirements as far as I can tell so. concentrate on that.

Comment: You are right. I lack information on what the purpose of my filter is. May i know other than the cutoff frequency, bandwidth, and (Lowpass/highpass) input and output impedance requirement, what other requirement that i neglected that i will need to take into account? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to state what your wanted signal is and why you feel it needs to be filtered.

Comment: Hey i updated the question with the new information ! let me know if i need to create a new question instead of updating the question.

Comment: Your filter is very steep. You are trying to have a 3dB point of 300kHz and be down 60dB at 500kHz. I know you are probably frustrated with all the input you are getting right now from everyone. It might help if you could take several steps back and explain what you are trying to do if you can. Like where is the input signal coming from, where is it going to, what do you actually know FOR SURE vs what are you just taking a guess at. One thing to consider is that in this frequency band, you can use active filters, or at least buffer the signal output with an op-amp.

Comment: So you may want to consider designing a high impedance filter, and then just buffer the output and put a 50 Ohm resistor in series to get your 50 Ohm output impedance.

Comment: i am actually glad that there was helpful comment pointing me in the right direction. This is a surge protection circuit and the input signal would be coming from a motor load being monitored by an PXI oscilloscope .  I am trying to avoid using op amp in the circuit as i am required to build a passive circuit .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To design a filter, you must specify the parameters;

1. attenuation or gain in passband
2. ripple in passband for >=2nd order filters (>=0dB)
3. stop band f-3dB = BW
4. stop band f-60dB defines order of filter needed or similar bandstop attenuation spec
5. Source impedance
6. Load impedance

In this example, a better design replaces 20 Ohm with 47uH and C = ~4.7nF . Thus attenuation in PB f = 6dB and breakpoint is at -9dB, while impedance remains at 50 Ohms to load in the passband.

### Thought experiment

What happens when \$Z_L(f)=2\pi f L= R_S+R_L\$ ? for R=100 total  L=53 uH and 47uH is a common 10% value.

Comment: Hey i updated the question with the new information ! let me know if i need to create a new question instead of updating the question.  If i am monitoring a signal source am i right to select 0 ripple in passband ?

Comment: @Wompalamba 1st order filters are always 0 dB ripple.  50 ohm source load are always 6dB loss, thus your spec may be 6+1.3 but why not use an LC filter?

Comment: Due to space constraint of the PCB board, i am afraid that the inductor might be too big in size.

Comment: SMT inductors are pretty small

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. My bad ,i forgot to mention that i am filtering an AC signal, i was told that an inductor in series might be a bad idea.

Comment: In series with what? matters.   impedance ratios determine Q relative to R

Comment: Hmm i feel that my concept might be wrong. But if i use inductance in series with the ac signal would the signal not be affected as inductance would resist the change in current. Therefore i feel that a fixed resistor is better.

Comment: The effective inductor impedance only rises above the R value at the breakpoint for a Q=0.7.  This ratio of omega*L /R determines the Q of the filter at the -3dB frequency with a C load. If Q is high then there will be peaking at the breakpoint.

Comment: Ah thanks, i understand where my concept is wrong and what you mean. Only at the -3db point, the impedance of the inductance will rise sharply. If there is peaking at the breakpoint am i wrong to say that it is now an under- damped filter ? I would need to read up on how to make it a critically damped filter.

Comment: There is no peaking in an RC filter just RLC but not in mine

Comment: I just tried replacing the resistor in the circuit with an inductor and you are right there is no peaking. I will try and figure out the transfer function so that i can size the inductor. In additional, I am also kind of curious as to why a filter need to be critically damped as i only know that it need to be but not why.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of approaches to filter design. Often, one of the first things to do is decide on the order of the filter. One way to do this is to look at how steep it is. This can be measured in dB per decade or dB per octave.

An octave is a doubling or halving of frequency. A decade is a multiplication or division by 10. The best way to explain this is by example.

If I want my cutoff at 100 Hz and I want to be down to -40dB at 1000 Hz, that means I am looking at a roll off of 40dB per decade (because 1000 Hz is 10x 100 Hz, so that is one decade).

An RC filter is a first order filter. It has a roll off of 20dB per decade (or 6dB per octave). So we know that we cannot achieve our desired specification with a single stage RC filter.

In general each L or C we add to our filter adds another 20dB per decade (or another 6dB per octave). So to get 40 dB in one decade we can add an inductor or cascade a second RC filter in series with the first one.

In your case, you are trying to get 60 dB of rolloff in less than one octave. This is what is known as a "brick wall" filter because very high attenuation is required very close to the passband. You would need to use something like 12 or more L's and C's to achieve this roll off.

Filters are a large and complex topic and I am by no means an expert. But hopefully I have taken you at least one step closer to understanding how to decide on filter specifications.

Comment: Wow that is a lot of LC, thank you ! I would need to clarify the project requirement i was given.